# Keras one-hot-encoder

Tags: python, numpy, keras, one-hot-encoding

I have an array, and use the to_categorical function in keras:

```
labels = np.array([1,7,7,1,7])
keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)
```

I get this response:

```
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
   [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
   [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I get only two columns? One for the 1 and one for the 7.

This is a possible way, but not a very good one:

```
labels = np.delete(labels, np.s_[0:1], axis=1)
np.delete(labels, np.s_[1:6], axis=1)
```

that gives:

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? Preferably by some "hidden" function in Keras utils or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can just index your array by *any* column that has a value:

```
cat = keras.utils.to_categorical(labels)
>>> cat
array([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])

# Select column if it has at least one value:
>>> cat[:,cat.any(0)]
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

You could also use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
cat = pd.get_dummies(labels).values
>>> cat
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_inverse` flag -

```
# Get unique IDs mapped to each group of elements
In [73]: unql, idx = np.unique(labels, return_inverse=True)

# Perform outer comparison for idx against range of unique groups
In [74]: (idx[:,None] == np.arange(len(unql))).astype(float)
Out[74]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```

Alternatively with direct usage of unique labels -

```
In [96]: (labels[:,None] == np.unique(labels)).astype(float)
Out[96]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 1.]])
```